Find the radius of the semicircle

A semicircle has its diameter $AC$, and two overlapping triangles $ABC$ and $ADC$ are drawn within it. Points $B$ and $D$ lie on the perimeter of the semicircle, and $D$ is the midpoint (see the figure below). The area of $ABC$ is $3cm^2$, and the distance between points $B$ and $D$ is $2cm$. Determine the radius of the semicircle.

I used the Pythagorean theorem to express $AD$ in terms of $r$, which gave me $AD=\sqrt2r$. Then I applied the cosine rule to triangles $DAB$, $BCD$, and $BOD$, knowing that $AD=CD$. I used the cosine rule for triangles $BAC$ and $BOC$.
However, I ended up with complex equations and multiple unknowns.


I would use coordinates so $A$ is at $(-r,0)$, $D$ is at $(0,r)$ etc.   Then if $B$ is at $(x,y)$ then $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and $x^2+(r-y)^2=4$ and $ry=3$, easily solved for $r$.

By Ptolemy's theorem we have $$r\sqrt 2 \times BC + 2\times 2r = AB \times r\sqrt 2$$
so
$$BC + 2\sqrt 2 = AB$$
We also know that $\tfrac{1}{2}AB\times BC=3$. Solving this system we get $BC=\sqrt 2$ and $AB = 3\sqrt 2$
Finally, $(2r)^2 = AB^2+BC^2=18+2=20$ so $r=\sqrt 5$.

We don't even need to solve the system if we're lazy: $AB^2 + BC^2 = (AB - BC)^2 + 2(AB \cdot BC) = (2\sqrt 2)^2 + 12 = 20$.

@MishaLavrov Nice catch!

I would use coordinates so $A$ is at $(-r,0)$, $D$ is at $(0,r)$, $C$ is at $(r,0)$
Then if $B$ is at $(x,y)$ then

$x^2+y^2=r^2$ since $B$ lies on the circle
$x^2+(r-y)^2=2^2$ since  $BD=2$
$ry=3$ as the area of $\triangle ABC$

and just subtract the second from the first (and tidy) to get $r^2=ry+2$
and substitute using the third to get $r^2=5$ and $r=\sqrt{5}$.

A typo: $RB$ should be $DB$
